# Set first letter capital Build.DEVICE?

Tags: java, xml

I have the following code.

```
String androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
String model = Build.MODEL;
String device = Build.DEVICE;

String var = "Android "+androidOS+"\n"+model+"\n"+device;
TextView tv = (TextView)view. findViewById(R.id.textView3);
tv.setText(var);
```

If I want the first letter of the String device = Build.DEVICE; is capital, how can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this

```
  device= device.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + device.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String str ="test";
str=str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+ str.substring(1);
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

No one is thinking of **SAMSUNG** it will do nothing with this but it is expected to be **Samsung**

```
String  device  = getInintCap(Build.DEVICE);

String getInintCap(String mString)
{
    if(mString != null && mString.length() > 1)
    {
        return mString.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + mString.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    else if(mString != null)
    {
        return mString.toUpperCase();
    }

    return null;
}
```

And also you shall think about **ONE_TOUCH_960C** or "Barak_OBAMA"